# Transfer from Jakarta Airport Link to MRT?

Tags: public-transport, jakarta, cgk

As I type this, the Jakarta MRT is scheduled to open next week.  [BNI City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNI_City_railway_station) (fka Sudirman Baru) station on the [Airport Rail Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soekarno%E2%80%93Hatta_Airport_Rail_Link) [appears to be quite close](https://goo.gl/maps/PvFDwAqWJDo) (~500m) to the upcoming MRT Dukuh Atas station, and this sounds pretty darn convenient for a planned business trip.

However, as previous visitors to Jakarta will know, walking 500m along the street can be quite the obstacle course, particularly if you have luggage.  **Are there any interchange facilities (tunnel, bridge, etc) for going from the Airport Rail Link to the MRT on foot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I checked this out today, and the connection is **feasible but not great**: doable with a backpack, less so with a suitcase.

There's no infrastructure as such (bridge, tunnel, etc), but both stations have signage pointing the way and [Google Maps's suggested route along Jl. Plaju](https://goo.gl/maps/omF2xALfXgy) appears walkable.  Just don't try walking up the extremely narrow car ramp if coming in from the MRT!

*July 2019 update*: An Indonesian source tells me a connecting tunnel between BNI City, Sudirman and MRT Dukuh Atas is now open!  Looking forward to checking this out on my next visit.

Comment: Are there sidewalks or are you on the shoulder of the road?

Comment: There are sidewalks, and they're less full of random stuff than most in Jakarta.